# How can I detect a chosen Isotope layout option from within Javascript to generate appropriate layout?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, gallery

I am trying to make a custom gallery post where a user may select Isotope layout modes (masonry, packery etc.). I don't want to create a custom template for each layout mode and then get it depending on whether a post includes a certain layout option. It seems that this solution will require a lot of duplicate code.

Is it possible to access the chosen post option from within a javascript file to generate a corresponding layout. May be some AJAX request to the appropriate PHP variable that holds this post option will do? If yes, how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The established technique of passing data to JavaScript in WordPress is [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Despite the name it's widely used for arbitrary data, outside of localization purposes.

So it is certainly possible to retrieve the necessary data and pass it to the script in this way.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any other techniques for doing what I'm intending to?